# Tor Launcher Command Analysis

Tags: shell, scripting, terminal, tor, launcher

I'm very beginner interested in scripting and right now I'm just curious what executes every part of the following command (from Tor launcher)

```
sh -c '"/home/user/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/home/user/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k
```

I found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/831847/what-is-the-sh-c-command that:

> "`sh` calls the program `sh` as interpreter and the `-c` flag means execute the following command as interpreted by this program."

Then there is a path to the `start-tor-browser` script and `--detach` (if I understand it correctly) just detaches Tor Browser process from Terminal.

I found some info about `--detach` here: https://superuser.com/questions/178587/how-do-i-detach-a-process-from-terminal-entirely

As far I also know, that `-x` means "make it executable", `&&` means "do also another command" and maybe `!` means "force it?".

Then there is `dummy %k` at the very end means symbolic link to the current directory (or file)?

I don't understand why are there double quotes: `' "`, this weird `||`, double parenthesis `([` and this `"$(dirname "$*")`.

If you understand this code better, please let me know :).

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You correctly described how the first part of command works. I'll try to answer some of your questions.
`||` is logical OR, so the rest of command line will be executed in a new *subshell* (that's what `(...)` neans) only if first command exits with status >0 i.e. fails.

`[ ! -x file ]`  checks if file is *not* (! means negation) executable (or does not exist).

`&&` is logical AND, so if that condition is true (no exec file in home dir) command line execution  will continue.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html